# Adobe flash record compressed samples from microphone

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air, speex

I want to capture audio samples from the microphone in my adobe AIR application and then save them to an flv file. I have the following code:

```
            mic.setSilenceLevel(0, DELAY_LENGTH);
            mic.codec  = SoundCodec.SPEEX;
            mic.encodeQuality = 6;
            mic.framesPerPacket = 1;
            mic.gain = 100;
            mic.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, micSampleDataHandler);
```

The problem is that I suspect that in my handler I am only getting raw samples and not compressed samples. The reason for my suspicion is that the number of bytes I get per message is equal to 20 ms (which my definition is 1 speex frame) of raw audio and not compressed audio. Also the number of bytes doesnt change if I change the encodeQuality. Reading the documentation suggests that adobe will only compress the audio before transmission to a flash media server or another peer. Is there a way to publish and read the stream locally in order to get compressed samples.
? Or any other way to get the compressed samples?

Answer (score 0):

You can encode your recording as mp3 using
http://code.google.com/p/flash-kikko/

Then save the file somewhere so you can incorporate that into an flv.

Comment: mp3 wont to do it for me. It has to be speex.